# FlowPane automatic horizontal space

Tags: javafx, flowpane

I have a FlowPane with equally-sized rectangular children and I have this problem with the space at the right end of the flowpane, when the space is not enough to fit another column of children, I want it to be equally divided between the other columns.

An example of what I want to achieve is how the file explorer in windows behaves, see the gif bellow for reference

[image: preferred behavior]

The default FlowPane behaviour doesn't look like this, it leaves the remaining width that can't fit a new child at the end of the region, as shown in the gif bellow

[image: default behavior]

And I failed to find any API or documentation to help me achieve my goal, I thought of adding a listener on the width property and adjusting the hGap property accordingly, something like

`[ flowPaneWidth - (sum of the widths of the children in one column) ] / (column count - 1)`

But again, I have no idea how to figure out the column count, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is a MRE if anyone wants to try their ideas :

```
public class FPAutoSpace extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(10, 10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {           
            root.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.GRAY));
        }

        ps.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        ps.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of thinking, I tried to implement the idea mentioned in the question  :

> adding a listener on the width property and adjusting the hGap property accordingly

but I added the listener on the needsLayout property instead, as follows :

```
public class FPAutoSpace extends Application {
    private double nodeWidth = 100;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setVgap(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            root.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(nodeWidth, nodeWidth, Color.GRAY));
        }

        root.needsLayoutProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {                   
            int colCount = (int) (root.getWidth() / nodeWidth);
            //added 4 pixels because it gets glitchy otherwise
            double occupiedWidth = nodeWidth * colCount + 4;
            double hGap = (root.getWidth() - occupiedWidth) / (colCount - 1);
            root.setHgap(hGap);
        });

        StackPane preRoot = new StackPane(root);
        preRoot.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        preRoot.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        ps.setScene(new Scene(preRoot, 600, 600));
        ps.show();
    }
}
```

Not sure how this will hold up in a multi-hundred node FlowPane but it worked for the MRE

[image: somewhat desired behaviour]

Let me know if you think there are better ways to do it.

Comment: An alternative is to subclass `FlowPane` (or create a new `Pane` subtype) and [override layoutChildren](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.java#L772) to customize the layout algorithm.  However, what you have done here in this answer is far easier to implement than the layoutChildren override would be, so much so that I wouldn't even try to create a solution based on a layoutChildren override.